# Inserting removing elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angularjs

I have a code that inserts a `div` with content whenever the user clicks a button. What is the angularjs way to insert or remove elements from the DOM?

Comment: angularJS way.. or whichever way, you'll have to write some code and post here if that doesn't work

Comment: Try http://plnkr.co/edit/NosehXDZByzmysJI5Igx?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

If the elements you want to add is somehow related to or near the button, use a directive.  Normally all DOM manipulation is performed by a directive.

However, there seems to be an exception to this rule: if you want to insert something like a modal dialog box -- i.e., something that doesn't have to be placed somewhere specific -- you might want to use a service.  Listen to a [few minutes of Misko](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=28m30s) regarding this.

If you do want a dialog, see http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog and here is an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15653255/215945) that uses it in a plunker.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use a directive to manipulate DOM, especially if the data is from control